# Glide memory leak in DefaultConnectivityMonitor

Tags: android, android-glide

LeakCanary has reported a memory leak in our app with following leak trace:

```
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: HeapAnalysisSuccess(heapDumpFile=/data/user/0/..../files/leakcanary/2020-05-24_08-24-07_502.hprof, createdAtTimeMillis=1590334865374, analysisDurationMillis=85525, applicationLeaks=[ApplicationLeak(className=<>.media.MediaControlActivity, leakTrace=
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ┬
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ android.provider.FontsContract
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (HomeApplication↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    GC Root: System class
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ static FontsContract.sContext
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ <>.application.HomeApplication
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Application is a singleton)
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    HomeApplication does not wrap an activity context
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ HomeApplication.mLoadedApk
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │                      ~~~~~~~~~~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ android.app.LoadedApk
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ LoadedApk.mReceivers
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │                ~~~~~~~~~~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ android.util.ArrayMap
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │               ~~~~~~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[]
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ array Object[].[9]
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │                     ~~~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ android.util.ArrayMap
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │               ~~~~~~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[]
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ array Object[].[58]
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │                     ~~~~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ ayf
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ ayf.a
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │          ~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ ayg
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ ayg.b
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │          ~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ als
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ als.b
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │          ~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ├─ alt
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │    ↓ alt.b
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: │          ~
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ╰→ <>.media.MediaControlActivity
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ​     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ​     key = 758a249e-d3c7-44e3-b633-4649a5574735
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ​     watchDurationMillis = 5397
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ​     retainedDurationMillis = 393
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: , retainedHeapByteSize=43842), ApplicationLeak(className=aym, leakTrace=
05-24 08:41:05.380044 16534 19408 D LeakCanary: ┬
```

After going through the mapping file, I see these are deobfuscated classes:

```
com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor$1 -> ayf

com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager$RequestManagerConnectivityListener -> als

com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor -> ayg

com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager -> alt
```

So it turns out, this is the same issue as https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3631.

I don't see any solution for this on the github issue link so creating a question here.

What are my possible solutions to avoid this leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to either stop using Glide, or contribute a fix to the library. The issue comments provide guidance on how to stop the leak from happening: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3631#issuecomment-488296849